# Converting a RawBoxes object to a workable expression

Tags: graphics

I have manged to turn an image into a `RawBoxes` expression. How do I turn in back into something I can use in `Graphics`? In particular, I want to rotate it.

Here is a minimum working example of how I messed up. Starting with

```
Graphics[{Green, Triangle[]}]
```

[image: bitmap]

I copied as bitmap into PowerPoint. Later I coped from PowerPoint into Mathematica using

```
a = paste;
```

Where "paste" is where I pasted the image.
If I do

```
Head[a]
```

it returns:  RawBoxes

Expressions like

```
Graphics[Rotate[a, π]]
```

Do not work (no surprise).
How do I convert an expression with `Head` RawBoxes back into a graphics that I can use again?
Thanks

Comment: When you converted into a bitmap you lost resolution independent `Graphics` quality. You can't recover `Graphics` object from that. At most, you may convert your `RawBoxes` into an `Image` object

Comment: Thanks for this warning.  I am aware that I will have to live with a bitmap. My target is to perform operations like rotating and resizing.

Comment: You write "operations like rotating and resizing" which is **exactly** what `Graphics` objects are capable of but **not** bitmapped `Image` objects. I strongly advise to stay away from bitmaps as long as possible and only for rasterization for viewing pusposes.

Comment: @Somos Of course I agree with you that working with `Graphics` objects is best. However, if you have got into the position of having `RawBoxs` perhaps because the image was never created in Mathematica what should you do? May I also point out that if you can convert to an `Image` then there is `ImageRotate` and `ImageResize` etc that enables you to to the same operation on images as you can on `Graphics.`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression) to turn a box expression into a normal expression. However, [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression) doesn't work with [`RawBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RawBoxes), [`Cell`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cell) or [`BoxData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxData). So, the following might work for you:

```
rawBoxesToExpression[RawBoxes[a_]] := rawBoxesToExpression[a]
rawBoxesToExpression[Cell[BoxData[b_], ___]] := rawBoxesToExpression[b]
rawBoxesToExpression[a_] := ToExpression[a]
```

For example:

```
rawBoxesToExpression[
    RawBoxes[Cell[BoxData@GraphicsBox[{RectangleBox[{0,0}],CircleBox[{0,0}]}]]]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However, it does not work in my case. Following your approach I have found that the images are contained in `RawBoxes[Cell[GraphhicsData[Metafile, CF5dJ6E]HGAYHf4PEfU^I6mgLb....]]]' Can this be unpacked to make an `Image`?

Comment: @Hugh Possibly, but I wold need the actual RawBoxes expression to play around with to find out.

Comment: I have been playing around more and I think I have found a solution. What I need to do is to `Rasterisze` the image and then I have an `Image` object. This can be worked with using `ImageRotate` , `ImageResize etc. I will post that as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to those that looked at this question and tried to find a solution. I have been working at the problem and found that I can `Rasterize` the `RawBoxes` to give me an `Image`. I can now do `ImageResize` and `ImageRotate`

Example:

Continuing with the item that has been pasted and is called `a` from original post.

```
b = Rasterize[a];
ImageCompose[ImageRotate[b, π/2], ImageResize[b, 100]]
```

[image: use of ImageCompose]

Hope that helps anyone who ends up with an item that has `Head` `RawBoxes`.